# Question about requiring files and the load path in Programming Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, require

I'm reading through "Programming Ruby 1.9". On page 208 (in a "Where to Put Tests" section), the book has the code organized as

```
roman
    lib/
        roman.rb
        other files...
    test/
        test_roman.rb
        other_tests...
    other stuff
```

and asks how we get our `test_roman.rb` file to know about the `roman.rb` file.

It says that one option that doesn't work is to build the path into `require` statements in the test code:

```
# in test_roman.rb
require 'test/unit'
require '../lib/roman'
```

Instead, it says a better solution is for all other components of the application to assume that the top-level directory of the application is in Ruby's load path, so that the test code would have

```
# in test_roman.rb
require 'test/unit'
require '/lib/roman'
```

and we'd run the tests by calling `ruby -I path/to/app path/to/app/test/test_roman.rb`.

**My question is**: is this realy the best way? It seems like

1. If we simply replaced `require '../lib/roman'` in the first option with `require_relative '../lib/roman'`, everything would work fine.
2. The assumption in the second option (that all components have the top-level directory in Ruby's load path) only works because we pass the `-I path/to/app` argument, which seems a little messy.

Am I correct that replacing `require` with `require_relative` fixes all the problems? Is there any reason to prefer the second option anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further on, that same book makes use of `require_relative` (Chapter 16, **Organizing your source code**) in the context of testing, so yes, I would say that using it is a Good Thing, since it *"always loads files from a path relative to the directory of the file that invokes it"*.

Of course, like @christiangeek noticed, require_relative is new in the 1.9 series, but there's a [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rbx-require-relative) that provides you with the same functionality.

It might be worth pointing out that the Pickaxe too provides a little method you can stick in your code in the same chapter I mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

`require_relative` does make the code cleaner but is only available natively on Ruby > 1.9.2. Which means if you want want your code to be portable to versions of Ruby < 1.9.2 you need to use a extension or the regular `require` AFAIK. The book is most likely a) written before 1.9.2 became widespread or b) providing a example for lowest common denominator.